# iterative if_else statement across many columns?

Tags: r

I have data representing intervals and I want to specify whether a value within a ID falls in an interval. so for example row one, 1.5 falls between `start` and `one_after`, so want=yes. then row 2, 3.3 falls between 2.4 and 3.4, etc. something like:

```
 df<-data.frame(ID=c(1, 1, 1,2,2,2,2), 
               start=c(1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 3.4,3.4,3.4,3.4),
               one_after=c(2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 4.4,4.4,4.4,4.4),
               two_after=c(3.4, 3.4, 3.4,5.4,5.4,5.4,5.4),
               three_after=c(4.4,4.4,4.4, 6.4,6.4,6.4, 6.4),
               four_after=c(NA, NA, NA, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4),
               value=c(1.5, 3.3, 4.45, 3.8, 4.5, 5.3, 6.5),
               want=c('yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes' ))
```

```
  ID start one_after two_after three_after four_after value want
1  1   1.4       2.4       3.4         4.4         NA  1.50  yes
2  1   1.4       2.4       3.4         4.4         NA  3.30  yes
3  1   1.4       2.4       3.4         4.4         NA  4.45   no
4  2   3.4       4.4       5.4         6.4        7.4  3.80  yes
5  2   3.4       4.4       5.4         6.4        7.4  4.50  yes
6  2   3.4       4.4       5.4         6.4        7.4  5.30   no
7  2   3.4       4.4       5.4         6.4        7.4  6.50  yes
```

now, I can make many ifelse statements like below to get a '1' indicator in a new column, but it is extremely messy and time consuming (see below), especially when I have 1000's of columns and many values.

```
HAVE:

df<-df%>%           mutate  (   within_start_one        =   ifelse( value   >= start &  value   <   one_after   ,   1,  0   ))          
df<-df%>%           mutate  (   within_one_two      =   ifelse( value   >=  one_after   &   value   <   two_after   ,   1   ,   0   ))
df<-df%>%           mutate  (   within_two_three        =   ifelse( value   >= two_after &  value   <   three_after ,   1,  0   ))          
df<-df%>%           mutate  (   within_three_four       =   ifelse( value   >=  three_after &   value   <   four_after  ,   1   ,   0   ))
```

I doubt there is a solution to have the single 'want' column. So,
I'm thinking there must be a way to iteratively do if else in a chunk of code (ie run across all possible `start, one_after, two_after etc.` columns and return many `within_start_one, within_one_two, etc.` columns) rather than typing out seemingly a million ifelse statements, but of course other solutions are welcome

Thanks,

Comment: Why is row 6 a "no"?

Comment: 5.30 falls outside of 5.4-6.4

Comment: The row 6 is anomaly.  Otherwise, this `c('no', 'yes')[(rowSums(df$value >= df[2:5] & df$value <= df[3:6], na.rm = TRUE) > 0) +1]` should work

Comment: @biostatguy12, but row 5 has 4.50 which is also not between 5.4-6.4 and it is "yes"...

Comment: row 5 value is 4.50 which is between 4.4 and 5.4, hence my hesitation with a single 'want' column it may make more sense if you run my "HAVE" code. But it is cumbersome, which I want to change

Comment: yes, but I would get 'no' from using the within_two_three value for that row (interested in the diagonals)

Comment: my 'want' is basically saying "ok does this 1st observation within ID=1 fall between start and one after?" then I can do "does within_start_one==1, if yes then 'yes'. 
"Does the next value fall between the intervals? is within_one_two==1, if yes then yes. "
"What about the third value in ID==1? It is zeros across all within_ vars, within_two_three==0 then want=='no'

Comment: I may remove the want column and focus more on the if_else if it is too confusing.. I know the within_ gives me values I can use, but it's just about typing out many ifelses. would love to reduce

Comment: By the way, what confused us is that you seem to be using the row number within each `ID` as information to decide which interval to compare with. But that is not explained in your question.

Comment: sorry @akrun... have made more clear

Comment: ok, I got it now.  Earlier, I was thinking not with respect to 'ID' column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without all those `_after` columns:

```
df %>% 
  select(ID, start, value) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    delay = row_number() - 1,
    want = ifelse(value >= start + delay & value < ( start + delay + 1), "yes", "no")
  )
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 5
> # Groups:   ID [2]
>      ID start value delay want 
>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
> 1     1   1.4  1.5      0 yes  
> 2     1   1.4  3.3      1 yes  
> 3     1   1.4  4.45     2 no   
> 4     2   3.4  3.8      0 yes  
> 5     2   3.4  4.5      1 yes  
> 6     2   3.4  5.3      2 no   
> 7     2   3.4  6.5      3 yes
> ```

Or probably a bit faster without `ifelse`:

```
df %>% 
  select(ID, start, value) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    delay = row_number() - 1,
    want = c('no', 'yes')[(value >= start + delay & value < ( start + delay + 1)) + 1]
  )
```

Comment: oh man this may work... may have saved me some serious run time. will try it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`, one option would be to create the logical matrix by comparing the alternate columns ('i1'), then use 'ID' as the grouping variable in `by`, extract the `diag`onal elements and change the TRUE/FALSE to `yes/no`

```
i1 <- df$value >= df[2:5] & df$value <= df[3:6]
c('no', 'yes')[unlist(by(replace(i1, is.na(i1), FALSE), df$ID,
                FUN = function(x) diag(as.matrix(x))+ 1))]
#[1] "yes" "yes" "no"  "yes" "yes" "no"  "yes"
```